# Open file from Gradle output in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

When I build my Gradle project inside IntelliJ IDEA and it contains compilation errors, I get something like this in the output:

> /path/to/file/Foo.java:9: error: some bad stuff!

Is it possible to configure IDEA so that it turns the "/path/to/file/Foo.java:9" into a link, which I can click on that it would then open the file in question at the correct location?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a feature, although it would be useful to have. (Of course you can always build in IntelliJ.) I'd expect that Android Studio related work will lead to deeper integration of Gradle compilation feedback (if it hasn't already).